# opengl es texturing problem android

Tags: android, opengl-es, texturing

i want to stretch or tile an opengl object from some bitmap. i use image of a part of bitmap.
but my ring and middle textured with a average color of image. if i change image color change, but picture is not showing.

and my full code here

```
  //  ..in init///


           gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);   
           textures = new int[3];
           bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.pizzaf);
           bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(   bitmap, 0, 0,    bitmap.getWidth(),
                   bitmap.getHeight(), null, true);
           bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.pizslice);
           bitmap1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(   bitmap1, 0, 0,    bitmap1.getWidth(),
                   bitmap1.getHeight(), null, true);
        // Tell OpenGL to generate textures.
           gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                   GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                   GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
//         gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
//                  GL10.GL_LINEAR);
//          gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
//                  GL10.GL_LINEAR);

           gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);

    }
```

and draw function

```
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap1, 0);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

                 GLUT.glutSolidTorus(gl,0.175f, 0.95f, 12, 48);
                 gl.glTranslatef(0,0, 0.2f);
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
                GLUT.glutSolidCone(gl, 1,0.01f, 12, 48);
            gl.glTranslatef(0,0, -0.4f);
            gl.glRotatef (180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap1, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        GLUT.glutSolidCone(gl, 1,0.01f, 12, 48);
```

please help anyone. i want to make a 3d pizza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 problems in your code:

1. You don't use texture objects properly
2. You reinitialize textures on each draw call
3. glutSolidCone doesn't provide texture coordinates (means: you can't texture it properly)

#### Fixing (1)

A texture is always loaded according to this scheme:

```
GLuint texture_object_name;

glGenTextures(1, 
              &texture_object_name); // you can create texture object names in batches

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, // may differ, depending on texture target (i.e. kind of texture)
              texture_object_name);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, …);   // </ depends on data format
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, …);  // <|
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, …); // <|
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, …);   // <|

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, // again the target, depends on the kind of texture creates
             0, // mipmap level
             GL_RGBA, // internal format, GL_RGBA is one possibility, there are others
             width, height, border, // border is usually 0
             GL_BGRA,                  // format of the data input
             GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8,  // type of the data input -- those must match the data
             texture_data );

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, …); // mipmapping on/off and other settings
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, …); // you should really set those
```

#### Fixing (2)

Once you fixed (1), you can fix (2). To switch textures while rendering you just have to call

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_object_name);
```

to use it in subsequent drawing calls.

#### Fixing (3)

(3) is fixed by defining the geometry yourself, supplying proper texture coordinates.

Comment: i added below code in init 
float textureCoordinates[] = {0.0f, 0.0f,
                   1.0f, 0.0f,
                   0.0f, 1.0f,
                   1.0f, 1.0f };
     ByteBuffer byteBuf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(textureCoordinates.length * 4);
     byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
     FloatBuffer textureBuffer = byteBuf.asFloatBuffer();
     textureBuffer.put(textureCoordinates);
     textureBuffer.position(0);
     gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);

its opengl es not opengl

Comment: Supplying a texture coordinate pointer will not help you, as long as you use glutSolidCode. How should OpenGL know how to relate the texture coordinates with the vertices? positions, texture coordinates, etc. together form a vector known as "Vertex". Just supplying some texture coordinates without relation to the vertices won't help you.

Comment: gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer); 

is not it bind texture with coordinates, if not what is the way?

Comment: Technically this binds texture coordinates, yes. But you just bound some unrelated values, that don't correspond to what glutSolidCone sends to OpenGL. It simply doesn't work that way. You need to provide the full set of vertex attributes. That is: Position, Normal, Texture Coordinates. To do so, DO NOT USE glutSolidCone – that one simply doesn't support texturing.